# c# Xdocument and descendants with the same name not working

Tags: c#, linq

Hi have the following XML with the same Transaction name (can't change it because this is how it comes from the origin):

```
<StoreCenter Operation="update" xmlns="http://something.com/rdc.xsd">
 <Transaction>
  <Transaction>
   <StoreID>30</StoreID>
   <TransactionID>2</TransactionID>
   <RegisterTransNumber>2</RegisterTransNumber>
    ....
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction>
   <StoreID>30</StoreID>
   <TransactionID>3</TransactionID>
   <RegisterTransNumber>2</RegisterTransNumber>
   ....
  <Transaction>
 <Transaction>
<StoreCenter>
```

I have the following code and I'm new in LINQ, I'm trying to retrive the StoreID for each Transaction Child:

```
XDocument Doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
       XNamespace ns = "http://something.com/rdc.xsd";
        foreach (var StoreCenter in Doc.Descendants(ns + "StoreCenter"))
        {
            foreach (var Transaction in StoreCenter.Descendants("Transaction"))
            {
                 foreach (var TransactionCh in Transaction.Descendants("Transaction"))
                 {
                    Console.WriteLine(Transaction.Element("StoreID").Value);
                 }

            }
        }
```

But I'm getting nothing, what am I doing wrong?, is this a good approach to retrieve these values?, please your advice will be appreciated

Comment: Thank you @Selman22, I tried your suggestion and changed this:

`code` (ns + "StoreCenter") (ns + "Transaction") and (ns + "Transaction")
                    
                        Console.WriteLine(TransactionCh.Element("StoreID").Value);
                     }
                }
            }


And I still get nothing, I've tried with and without the curly braces, and yes i got it wrong at first, it should've been:

    "{" + ns + "}"

Comment: Again me, @Selman22, I added the `code`ns+`code` in the following child nodes and I'm a NullReferenceExpection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML is correctly closed (i assume that the `Transaction` and `StoreCenter` nodes from the example XML are closed), then - yes, your approach using LINQ2XML is correct.

You could enhance the code using the [XElement.GetDefaultNamespace() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getdefaultnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the default namespace easily (easier than typing). A solution could look like this:

```
    var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<StoreCenter Operation=""update"" xmlns=""http://something.com/rdc.xsd"">
    <Transaction>
        <Transaction>
            <StoreID>30</StoreID>
            <TransactionID>2</TransactionID>
            <RegisterTransNumber>2</RegisterTransNumber>
        </Transaction>
        <Transaction>
            <StoreID>30</StoreID>
            <TransactionID>3</TransactionID>
            <RegisterTransNumber>2</RegisterTransNumber>
        </Transaction>
    </Transaction>
</StoreCenter>";

var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml); // or XDocument.Load(xml);
var ns = xmlDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var transactions = xmlDocument
                    .Root                           // the StoreCenter root node
                    .Element(ns + "Transaction")    // the enclosing Transaction node
                    .Elements(ns + "Transaction")   // only Transaction subnodes
                    .ToList();
foreach (var transaction in transactions)
{
    var storeId = transaction.Element(ns + "StoreID").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(storeId);
}
```

And the output is:

```
30
30
```

Comment: your solution worked exactly as I wanted it to, great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the curly brace from here:

```
Doc.Descendants("{" + ns + "StoreCenter")
                ^^^
```

And you should specify the namespace with child elements as well.Like: `StoreCenter.Descendants(ns + "Transaction")` and `Transaction.Descendants(ns + "Transaction")`

if you just want to get `Transaction` elements you can just to : `Doc.Descendants(ns + "Transaction")` or `Doc.Root.Element(ns + "Transaction").Elements(ns + "Transaction");` (assuming StoreCenter is the root element)